# Completar Valores Columna

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla que me genera los siguientes resultados:

```
ID    F_Inicio
1     01/01/2001
NULL  02/01/2001
NULL  03/01/2001
2     04/01/2001
NULL  05/01/2001
```

La colaboración es para lo siguientes resultados:

```
ID    F_Inicio
1     01/01/2001
1     02/01/2001
1     03/01/2001
2     04/01/2001
2     05/01/2001
```

Convertir los valores NULL en ese consecutivo anterior, el ejemplo es muy básico pero los registros que pueden existir entre 1,2,3... puede variar entre 100 o 200 registro para llegar al siguiente ID (1,2,3...N).

Comment: Seria muy bueno conocer que version de sql-server estas utilizando

Comment: En el momento estoy trabajando en SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar para ayudarte [CTE (common table expression )](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), entonces puedes realizar una consulta recursiva.
Si bien se puede realizar recursivamente, arme un ejemplo rapido para que veas como obtener con una subconsulta (es lo primero que se me ocurrio, pero se podria mejorar)

Entonces

1. Armamos una CTE en base a una consulta (en el ejemplo arme desde una insert a una variable de tabla)
2. En la CTE se agrega una columna que nos ayuda a buscar los anteriores (con el ROW_NUMBER), se llama la columna Fila, y es solamente para eso, "ayudar"
3. Luego ya se puede utilizar la CTE directamente.

Dale una mirada

Un ejemplo

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/fernandezja/bbb8847fc72719f81d02fb14f4d5c8a8.js"></script>
```

Aqui pego el codigo para referencia (por si no funciona lo anterior embebido)

```
DECLARE @DemoTable TABLE (
    ID INT NULL,
    F_Inicio DATE NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @DemoTable
VALUES (1     , '2001-01-01'),
    (NULL  , '2001-02-02'),
    (NULL  , '2001-02-03'),
    (2     , '2001-02-04'),
    (NULL  , '2001-02-05'),
    (NULL  , '2001-02-06'),
    (NULL  , '2001-02-07'),
    (NULL  , '2001-02-08'),
    (3  , '2001-02-09'),
    (NULL  , '2001-02-10')



;WITH CTEDemo
AS(
SELECT 
    ID, 
    F_Inicio,
    Fila = ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1000))
FROM @DemoTable
)


SELECT 
ID = CASE 
        WHEN CTE1.ID IS NULL THEN ISNULL((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM CTEDemo CTE2 
                                    WHERE CTE2.ID IS NOT NULL 
                                          AND  CTE2.Fila < CTE1.Fila), 0)
        ELSE CTE1.ID
     END , 
F_Inicio
FROM CTEDemo CTE1
```

Enlaces

- [CTE (common table expression )](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- Ejemplo: completar-valores-columna-con-CTE.sql https://gist.github.com/fernandezja/bbb8847fc72719f81d02fb14f4d5c8a8

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Comment: Estupendo, exactamente lo que necesitaba, Gracias.